# Solve for $a$ in the formula $\frac{x^a}{a}=b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rearrange this formula to find $a$ in terms of $x$ and $b$:

$$\frac{x^a}{a}=b$$

So far I can rearrange up to here, but I don't know what to do next to get $a$ by itself:

$$x^a=ab$$

$$\log_x(ab)=a$$

$$\log_x(a)+\log_x(b)=a$$

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly solve for $a$ in terms of $x$ and $b$ using ordinary school algebra operations and precalculus functions (exponentiation, logarithms, etc.). Do you have a reason to suspect that this can be done, such as it was a problem in a text where you are supposed to do this, or is this something that came up as a by-product of something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone has assigned this as a precalculus problem, they must be pulling your leg.  They are essentially asking about the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  To be precise, the "answer" is

$$a={-1\over\ln x}W\left({-\ln x\over b}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, I started writing my answer before you edited yours to include the solution. (+1)

Comment: Letting $u = ab$, I get $\frac{\ln u}{u} = \frac{\ln x}{b},$ which strongly suggests to me that it can't be "solved", because I suspect being able to solve $\frac{\ln u}{u} = c$ ($c$ a constant) will imply being able to solve some known non-solvable equation (analogous to reducibility arguments in recursion theory). However, I don't know enough to definitively conclude the original poster's equation is not solvable. On the other hand, I think non-solvability can be shown from the formula you came up with using the fact that the inverse of the Lambert function is not "precalculus expressible".

Comment: Hummm..."analogous to reducibility arguments in recursion theory" is not a particularly appropriate analogy to use in the present context. More appropriate is: analogous to proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{8}$ by showing the rationality of $\sqrt{8}$ easily implies the rationality of $\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I like your analogy with $\sqrt8$ and $\sqrt2$.  robjohn, I'm sorry I didn't see your answer before you removed it.  I had decided I should be specific, since it wasn't totally obvious how the W function related to what the OP asked.

Comment: @BarryCipra: it was just a derivation of the formula you cited. It seemed overkill after you added the formula.