# Solve exponential equation $(1−ax^2)∗e^{bx^2}=c$ for x. transcendental algebraic equation?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

is it possible to solve an equation with the given form analytically?

$$
(1-ax^2)*e^{bx^2}=c
$$
$$
e^{bx^2}-ax^2e^{bx^2}=c
$$

I've already tried it using a logarithmic function but I cannot manage it to get $x$ on one site.

I need to get this equation to the generalized transcendental algebraic equation:
$$
e^{-cx} = a (x-b)
$$

in order to solve it with $x=b+\frac{1}{c}W(c \frac{e^{-cb}}{a})$
where $W$ is theLambert function.

Am I right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There was a question similar to this asked yesterday.  See my [answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690258/solve-for-a-in-the-formula-fracxaa-b/690265#comment1447338_690265).  The solution, to the extent there is one, involves the Lambert W function.

**Added later**:  Here are the steps I followed to relate the OP's equation to the [W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  First, multiply both sides by $-b/a$ to get

$$-{bc\over a}=\left(bx^2-{b\over a} \right)e^{bx^2}$$

Next multiply both sides by $e^{-{b\over a}}$ to get

$$-{bc\over a}e^{-{b\over a}}=\left(bx^2-{b\over a} \right)e^{bx^2-{b\over a}}$$

This is now of the form $z=We^W$, where $z=(-bc/a)e^{-b/a}$ and $W=bx^2-(b/a)$.  Hence

$$x=\sqrt{W\left(-{bc\over a}e^{-b/a}\right)+{b\over a}\over b}$$

If there were some other, elementary expression for $x$ as a function of $a$, $b$, and $c$, then you would be able to unwind things and get an elementary expression for the W function.

Comment: can you be a little bit precise?I still have the variable $b$ in the exponent. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last question: how do I evaluate $W$?

Comment: @MichaelScott, for the most part, values of the W function can only be approximated numerically.  The Wikipedia article can point you to methods.  Good luck!

Comment: is it also possible to solve: $e^{bx^2}-ax^2e^{bx^2+dx}=c$ ?

Comment: @MichaelScott, you should really ask this as a separate question (and you should accept the answer I've given to your original question here).  But the answer is no:  If there were an elementary expression for the new equation, then there'd be an elementary expression for the old one, simply by setting $d=0$.  (Whether you can solve it with the W function is less clear.  That's why you should ask it as a new question.)